# Play Stream in Android from link

Tags: android, flash, stream, television

I have link of flash player playing live channel,I want to stream it in android using VideoView.

Link of channel is

[link](http://autoharraj.com/saudi-madinah2.html)

I did streaming using

String url= "http://X.X.X.X/live/X/playlist.m3u8";
view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));

but I am not able to get the link now from the live stream tv.

Answer (score 0):

m3u8 is not supported by Android in default, if you want to do live streaming you can either use HLS format ( which is only supported in new versions, not backward supported) or you can use Vitamio, which support live stream via m3u8 and a couple of other formats as well

http://www.vitamio.org/en/

Comment: m3u8 is working on Android, I am playing it using Vide View on ICS.

Comment: i said it's not supported in **default**, via plug-ins of course you can play